# Airflow - GCP - files from DAG folder are not showing up

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm new to GCP . I have a sample python script created in a GCP environment which is running fine. I want to schedule this in `Airflow`. I copied the file in `DAG` folder in the environment (`gs://us-west2-*******-6f9ce4ef-bucket/dags`), but it's showing up in the airflow DAG ..
This is the location in airflow config.
`dags_folder = /home/airflow/gcs/dags`

Pls do let me know how to get my python code to show up in airflow..do i have to setup any other things. I kept all default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is already correct, wherein you placed your python script in your `gs://auto-generated-bucket/dags/`. I'm not sure if you were able to use the `airflow` library in your script, but this library will let you configure the behavior of your DAG in airflow. You can see an example in the [Cloud Composer quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart#creating_a_dag).

You can check an in-depth tutorial of DAGs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html).

Sample DAG (test_dag.py) that prints the dag_run.id:

```
# test_dag.py #

import datetime
import airflow
from airflow.operators import bash_operator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'this_is_the_test_dag', ## <-- This string will be displayed in the AIRFLOW web interface as the DAG name ##
        'catchup=False',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    # Print the dag_run id from the Airflow logs
    print_dag_run_conf = bash_operator.BashOperator(
        task_id='print_dag_run_conf', bash_command='echo {{ dag_run.id }}')
```

`gs://auto-generated-bucket/dags/` gcs location:
[image]

Airflow Web server:
[image]

Comment: Thx Ricco..it helped me to go over the problem and fix it..here is what it's happening ..I have my python script on the environment but not able to copy that to the DAG folder directly ..so I have to create python file on my desktop ..upload to DAG folder when I do so the type of the file is not showing up as x-python in GCP cloud ..that's the reason for not showing up in the airflow..I have to manually change the type of the file by going to edit meta data properties..is there any way to avoid this 1 ..pls suggest

Comment: @GCPStart If you installed the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart), you can run this command on your terminal `gcloud composer environments storage dags import --environment "you-environment-name-here" --location "your-environment-location" --source "/full_path_of_your_code/your_python_script.py"`. This command will copy your script to the DAGs folder of your cloud composer. You can see more details on how to use the gcloud command [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart#uploading_the_dag_to).